# How are C files included in freeSwitch (kind of framework for calls)?

Tags: c, web, freeswitch

Today I downloaded `Freeswitch` that (based on what I read) allows me to have a messaging (audio and video calls) server in my computer. I am not very good in programming. When analysing the files contained in its .zip file, I noticed that almost all the files were written in C++.
However based on my knowledge, C files need to be compiled before they can be used (maybe I am wrong). If so, Why C files??

I ask this question because I was building some kind of web messaging app. I implemented text chat, send image, audio, attachment. I did it using simply HTML, JAVASCRIPT, PHP, SQL and a little XML. When it comes to audio call and Video call, I cannot start (because I found it more complex). So I tried to find an easy alternative that took me to `freeswitch`.
I do not know if it is up to me to compile them or not.

Note: I did not install it.
Thank you!!

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Comment: I meant Why, not How!!

Answer (score 1):

[FreeSwitch](https://freeswitch.org) is an open-source software-based PBX written in C.  So yes, it needs to be compiled.  However, the FreeSwitch website provides precompiled binaries if you just want to use the FreeSwitch software as-is:

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Installation

You don't need the [source code](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse) unless you are planning on modifying it, in which case you will then have to compile it for any changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

FreeSwitch is open-source tool written in C. FreeSwitch uses many libraries. So to compile FreeSwitch you have to first install all dependency of FreeSwitch then you have to `configure` and `make`, `make install` the FreeSwitch Source.

I have wrote many custom module in FreeSwitch using C for Callcenter, conference, class4-switch, class5-switch, class4/5 switch.